# Difference between API versions v2beta1 and v2beta2 in Horizontal Pod Autoscaler?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, autoscaling

The Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler walkthrough in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/ explains that we can perform autoscaling on custom metrics. What I didn't understand is when to use the two API versions: v2beta1 and v2beta2. If anybody can explain, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21):

The first metrics **autoscaling/V2beta1** doesn't allow you to scale your pods based on custom metrics. That only allows you to scale your application based on `CPU` and `memory` utilization of your application

The second metrics **autoscaling/V2beta2** allows users to autoscale based on custom metrics. It allow autoscaling based on metrics coming from outside of Kubernetes. A new External metric source is added in this api.

```
metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
```

It will identify a specific metric to autoscale on based on metric name and a label selector. Those metrics can come from anywhere like a stackdriver or prometheus monitoring application and based on some query from prometheus you want to scale your application.

It would always better to use `V2beta2` api because it can do scaling on CPU and memory as well as on custom metrics, while V2beta1 API can scale only on internal metrics.

The snippet I mentioned in answer denotes how you can specify the target CPU utilisation in `V2beta2` API

Comment: GKE tutorial uses v2beta1 with custom metrics: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/custom-metrics-autoscaling

Comment: Do you know how to install/enable v2beta2? It does not appear in the list when I run `kubectl api-versions`

Comment: I used scaling on custom metrics from Prometheus and it worked with autoscaling/V2beta1.

Comment: I scaled on custom metrics from Prometheus using Prometheus Adapter(https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter) and it worked with autoscaling/V2beta1

Comment: external metrics support has nothing to do with v2beta2. Check specs for exhaustive diffs. One major change we could note relates to .spec.behavior introduction in v2beta2

Comment: v2beta1 supports external metrics, I use the one based on SQS length

Comment: with v2beta1 it is also possible to use custom metrics

Answer (score 13):

UPDATE: **`v2beta1` is deprecated in 1.19** and you should use `v2beta2` going forward.

Also, `v2beta2` added the **new api field `spec.behavior` in 1.18** which allows you to define how fast or slow pods are scaled up and down.

---

**Originally, both versions were functionally identical but had different APIs.**

`autoscaling/v2beta2` was released in Kubernetes version 1.12 and the release notes state:

> - We released autoscaling/v2beta2, which cleans up and unifies the API

The "cleans up and unifies the API" is referring to that fact that `v2beta2` consistently uses the `MetricIdentifier` and `MetricTarget` objects:

```
spec:
  metrics:
    external:
      metric: MetricIdentifier
      target: MetricTarget
    object:
      describedObject: CrossVersionObjectReference
      metric: MetricIdentifier
      target: MetricTarget
    pods:
      metric: MetricIdentifier
      target: MetricTarget
    resource:
      name: string
      target: MetricTarget
    type: string
```

In `v2beta1`, those fields have pretty different specs, making it (in my opinion) more difficult to figure out how to use.

Answer (score 4):

**How to check differences between HPA versions in general?**

I would provide additional answer which I think would be also suitable for other version differences in the future.

1. Run `kubectl api-versions` and check which version your cluster is supporting.
2. Go to the [K8S API site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#-strong-api-groups-strong-) and comapre autoscaling versions:

   [MetricSpec v2beta2 autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#metricspec-v2beta2-autoscaling) Vs [MetricSpec v2beta1 autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#metricspec-v2beta1-autoscaling) .

   (*) Just notice that you're in the correct K8S version in the url:

   https:// kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/**v1.23**/#metricspec-v2beta1-autoscaling

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to drive the horizontal pod autoscaler with a custom external metric, and only v2beta1 is available to you (I think this is true of GKE still), we do this routinely in GKE.  You need:

1. A stackdriver monitoring metric, possibly one you create yourself,
2. If the metric isn't derived from sampling Stackdriver logs, a way to publish data to the stackdriver monitoring metric, such as a cronjob that runs no more than once per minute (we use a little python script and Google's python library for monitoring_v3), and
3. A custom metrics adapter to expose Stackdriver monitoring to the HPA (e.g., in Google, `gcr.io/google-containers/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter:v0.10.0`).  There's a tutorial on how to deploy this adapter [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/custom-metrics-autoscaling).  You'll need to ensure that you grant the required RBAC stuff to the service account running the adapter, as shown [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/blob/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter/deploy/production/adapter.yaml).  You may or may not want to grant the principal that deploys the configuration cluster-admin role as described in the tutorial; we use Helm 2 w/ Tiller and are careful to grant least privilege to Tiller to deploy.

Configure your HPA this way:

```
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
metadata:
 ...
spec:
   scaleTargetRef:
      kind: e.g., StatefulSet
      name: name-of-pod-to-scale
      apiVersion: e.g., apps/v1
   minReplicas: 1
   maxReplicas: ...
   metrics:
     type: External
     external: 
       metricName: "custom.googleapis.com|your_metric_name"
       metricSelector:
          matchLabels:
             resource.type: "generic_task"
             resource.labels.job: ...
             resource.labels.namespace: ...
             resource.labels.project_id: ...
             resourcel.labels.task_id: ...
       targetValue: e.g., 0.7 (i.e., if you publish a metric that measures the ratio between demand and current capacity)
```

If you ask kubectl for your HPA object, you won't see autoscaling/v2beta1 settings, but this works well:

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/autoscaling/v2beta1/namespaces/your-namespace/horizontalpodautoscalers/your-autoscaler | jq
```

So far, we've only exercised this on GKE.  It's clearly Stackdriver-specific.  To the extent that Stackdriver can be deployed on other public managed k8s platforms, it might actually be portable.  Or you might end up with a different way to publish a custom metric for each platform, using a different metrics publishing library in your cronjob, and a different custom metrics adapter.  We know that one exists for Azure, for example.