# HPA labelSelector not filtering external metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, autoscaling

I'm trying to setup custom metrics based autoscaler on a EKS cluster (v1.13.10-eks-5ac0f1) but looks like the labelSelector filter for external metrics labels is not filtering.

Using [k8s-prometheus-adapter](https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter) and [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/)(v0.3.6) I've managed to export metrics from prometheus as kubernetes external metrics.

The metric is correctly exported and visible on the kubernetes api:

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/*/sqs_queue_messages"

{
  "kind": "ExternalMetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/%2A/sqs_queue_messages"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metricName": "sqs_queue_messages",
      "metricLabels": {
        "__name__": "sqs_queue_messages",
        ...
        "queue_name": "temp-queue"
      },
      "timestamp": "2019-11-07T21:14:44Z",
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "metricName": "sqs_queue_messages",
      "metricLabels": {
        "__name__": "sqs_queue_messages",
        ...
        "queue_name": "random-queue"
      },
      "timestamp": "2019-11-07T21:14:44Z",
      "value": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

**horizontal-pod-autoscaler.yml**

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: api
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: api
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
    - external:
        metricName: sqs_queue_messages
        metricSelector:
          matchLabels:
            queue_name: temp-queue
        targetAverageValue: "100"
      type: External
```

The problem is that the HPA is not selecting just the metric with the matched label, infact by looking at the logs I can see that the following call is performed

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/*/sqs_queue_messages?labelSelector=queue_name%3Dtemp-queue"
```

The expected result is just 1 item (the one matching **queue_name: temp-queue** label) but instead the filter is ignored and all the results are returned.

Comment: can you try changing your apiVersion to `autoscaling/v2beta2`, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459735/12201084) for explanation

Comment: Hi @HelloWorld thank you for the response, by the way i tried to change the apiVersion to v2beta2 but the hpa is still not working correctly, in particular the request to **kubectl get --raw "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/*/sqs_queue_messages?labelSelector=queue_name%3Dqueue-temp"** is ignoring the labelSelector returning all the series instead of just the selected one

Comment: Hey @GaruGaru any update on this question?

Comment: I found a lead here, if anyone wants to follow-up on this question: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/issues/255