# HorizontalPodAutoscaler manifest not filtering metricSelector.matchLabels

Tags: kubernetes, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, prometheus-adapter

We are working with Redis Queues and exposing some metrics with Prometheus Adapter so then we can use HPA to scale our deployments based on the number of records with "Queued" status.

The problem I'm seeing is that no matter how I try to filter the HPA metrics, it is considering the whole number instead of the specific `matchLabels.metricSelector` I'm providing.

The HPA is working as it should, but without considering the Scanner number, but considering everything returned from the External API.

See below.

"**CloneRepo**" and "**Semgrep**" would sum 370.
If I apply the HPA only for "semgrep" scanner, it would scale to 13 PODs because of the total sum of 370, instead of considering the expect value of 0.

It seems it's not considering (or it's incorrectly defined) the `matchLabels.metricSelector` in the manifest.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong here?

K8s: 1.27 (running on AWS EKS)
Namespace: scanners

A simple sample of RQ_JOBS metrics from Prometheus look like this:

clonerepo - 370 records in "Queued" status
semgrep   - 0   records in "Queued" status

- **Prometheus Metrics** for `rq_jobs`. Notice the "scm_instance" and "queue" labels.

```
rq_jobs{container="rq-exporter-bitbucket", endpoint="http-metrics", instance="100.64.13.45:9726", job="rq-exporter-bitbucket", namespace="scanners", pod="rq-exporter-bitbucket-5879d9bd4b-zcnns", queue="clonerepo", scm_instance="rq-exporter-bitbucket", service="rq-exporter-bitbucket", status="queued"}
370
rq_jobs{container="rq-exporter-bitbucket", endpoint="http-metrics", instance="100.64.13.45:9726", job="rq-exporter-bitbucket", namespace="scanners", pod="rq-exporter-bitbucket-5879d9bd4b-zcnns", queue="semgrep", scm_instance="rq-exporter-bitbucket", service="rq-exporter-bitbucket", status="queued"}
0
```

**HPA Manifest**

- Notice the matchLabels section, this is where we expect to filter the Metric Name exposed by Prometheus Adapter and the Queue and SCM Instance.
- If I use `autoscaling/v1` with `targetAverageValue` it works. When I switch to `autoscaling/v2`, then the HPA goes to CPU Utilization, which is kind of different of what I've read over the internet. Anyway, this is not the problem, with v1 it's working based on Numbers, but not filtering as expected.

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: hpa-semgrep
  namespace: scanners
  annotations:
    autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/metrics: |
      [
        {
          "type": "External",
          "external": {
            "metricName": "hpa_rq_jobs",
            "metricSelector": {
              "matchLabels": {
                  "queue": "semgrep",
                  "scm_instance": "rq-exporter-bitbucket"
              }
            },
            "targetAverageValue": "30"
          }
        }
      ]
spec:
  maxReplicas: 20
  minReplicas: 2
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: deploy-scanner-semgrep
```

This is the Prometheus adapater definition:

```
external:
    - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"rq_jobs", namespace="scanners", scm_instance!="", status="queued"}'
      resources:
        overrides:
          namespace:
            resource: namespace
      name:
        matches: ^(.*)
        as: "hpa_rq_jobs"
      metricsQuery: sum(rq_jobs{status='queued', scm_instance!=""}) by (scm_instance, queue)
```

We can query the available metrics, they "look good" apparently.

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/scanners/hpa_rq_jobs| jq .
{
  "kind": "ExternalMetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {},
  "items": [
    {
      "metricName": "hpa_rq_jobs",
      "metricLabels": {
        "queue": "scmclone_repo",
        "scm_instance": "rq-exporter-bitbucket"
      },
      "timestamp": "2023-11-26T11:45:26Z",
      "value": "370"
    },
    {
      "metricName": "hpa_rq_jobs",
      "metricLabels": {
        "queue": "semgrep",
        "scm_instance": "rq-exporter-bitbucket"
      },
      "timestamp": "2023-11-26T11:45:26Z",
      "value": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

From this point, we would expect the HPA for semgrep to keep with 2 nodes, but instead, it goes to 13 nodes which is the total number of records of the exposed metric.

```
            "metricSelector": {
              "matchLabels": {
                  "queue": "semgrep",
                  "scm_instance": "esi-bitbucket"
              }
            },
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Based on many documentation, Custom Metrics can be exposed and used at HPA.
While `autoscaling/v1` focus is CPU and Memory, while `autoscaling/v2` allows custom and external metrics as well other specs.

From the links in the suggested answers, this one fits to the description.
[HPA labelSelector not filtering external metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58757350/hpa-labelselector-not-filtering-external-metrics).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is at Prometheus Adapter custom/external metrics rules.

See the reply here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/issues/255#issuecomment-588471197

In short, even when providing filters in your `metricsQuery`, it needs the `<<.LabelMatchers>>`.

```
- seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"rq_jobs", namespace="scanners", scm_instance!="", status="queued"}'
      resources:
        overrides:
          namespace:
            resource: namespace
      name:
        matches: ^(.*)
        as: "hpa_rq_jobs"
      metricsQuery: sum(rq_jobs{status="queued", namespace="scanners", scm_instance!="", <<.LabelMatchers>>}) by (scm_instance, queue)
```